# Como cambiar de sql server 2005 a 2008 y de collection

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Estoy migrando mi base de datos que se encuentra en Sql server 2005 con collection SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS y la quiero migrar a Sql server 2008 R2 con collection SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP850_CI_AS, cuando le cambio la collection en propiedades opciones me da un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cuál error te da?

Comment: lo puse en la pregunta

Comment: podrías incluir en tu pregunta las sentencias DDL para los objetos que menciona el error? Para ver cómo son dependientes del collation. Por ahora no es posible que cambies el collation de la base de datos hasta que no resuelvas esa dependencia.

Comment: donde puedo ver esas sentencias

Comment: ah, no tienes muchas alternativas para solucionar esto. Me imagino que tienes vistas/funciones/procedimientos almacenados con schemabinding. Esto te impide cambiar directamente el collation de la base de datos.

Comment: si tengo tiene mucha informacion, entonces no hay forma de cambiar ?

Comment: mmmmm tendrías que quitarles el schemabinding a esos objetos, cambiar el collation de la base, y volver a agregarles schemabinding

Comment: wow imagina que esta base de datos tiene 200 tablas